# ld terminates compiling wxmsw28_core_gcc_custom.dll on Windows with MinGW

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw, mingw32

I am busy compiling wxWindows on Windows 7 32 bit with MinGW.

The process does not finish, however; ld terminates after trying to compile `wxmsw28_core_gcc_custom.dll`. I am busy watching my system now and ld has stopped working again after consuming 1.95 GB private memory and it was utilizing most of one processor.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I just followed the process of `./configure` and `make` from the MinGW shell.

Where do I start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the swap file size. 
What happens when you call `make` command again?
Have you tried to use some newer version of MinGW or this happens with the latest one?

Comment: Thanks Marc Bolan ;-) I am using the latest MinGW (downloaded today) and my swap file is currently set to 3171 MB. I don't think I have hit that limit yet, according to what I saw in the process explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. The compile always broke off at 1.9 GB.

The only thing that helped me was switch off monolith. In config.gcc

```
# Multiple libraries or single huge monolithic one? [0,1]
MONOLITHIC = 0

# Build GUI libraries? [0,1]
USE_GUI = 1
```

Now in wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll I have 15 Dll's.

Hope that helps ;-)

EDIT:

I've assumed that in your config.gcc "shared = 1".

I think it's better to make all settings in the config.gcc. Tip set also RUNTIME_LIBS = dynamic.

Search the following settings and replaced them with

```
# What type of library to build? [0,1]
SHARED = 1

# Compile Unicode build of wxWidgets? [0,1]
UNICODE = 1

# Type of compiled binaries [debug,release]
BUILD = release

# Multiple libraries or single huge monolithic one? [0,1]
MONOLITHIC = 0

RUNTIME_LIBS = dynamic
```

Comment: The only config.gcc file I could find was under build\msw, so I assume it's right, and it already has MONOLITHIC ?= 0 and USE_GUI ?= 1 (why '?=' and not '=', but anyway). Busy trying to compile again after starting with a clean install and make.

Comment: After running ../configure in a new, clean build dir, it tells me "Should wxWidgets be compiled into single library?       no". But I still get the same problem (ld fails after consuming 1.9GB memory).

Answer (score 0):

After failing with the the `../configre` and `make` option to compiling, I followed the instructions given here: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW and instead used

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
```

This time it compiled OK. Now I have my DLLs under `lib\gcc_dll`.